# What's the rule to convert CocoaAPI to MacRuby API

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macruby

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:     (BOOL)flag
{
[self showWindow:self];
return YES;
}
```

how to convert this method to MacRuby ?

I tried

```
def applicationShouldHandleReopen(the_application, k)   
    @window.makeKeyAndOrderFront
end
```

but not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the selector syntax for the 2nd argument, e.g.:

```
def applicationShouldHandleReopen(the_application, hasVisibleWindows:k)
    ...
end
```

See http://www.macruby.org/documentation/tutorial.html for more on this exact topic.